# Can you grab an older timestamped version of a MS SourceSafe project?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I need an old version of a project from Microsoft Source Version Control System.  Specifically, there are changes across several files that need to be reverted back to an older release due to errors.  Is this possible in that program?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm guessing you didn't create a label?  After every release you should label the project to create a point you can go back to.   Failing that I think it's strictly a manual process of getting each file back to a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

It's been many years since I used SourceSafe (thank Deity, get out while you can!), but I believe it's possible with the command line tool, ss, using perhaps the `ss Get` command:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/661w6e3d(v=vs.80).aspx

You can give a date using the -V option:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cya2z0zz(v=vs.80).aspx